# How to use masking with structures to modify only selected atoms?

Tags: pyiron

I want to modify the position of atoms that fulfil a specific condition.

Currently, I can apply translation to all atoms or one atom but not multiple selected atoms.

```py
from pyiron import Project
pr = Project('test')
uc = pr.create_ase_bulk('Fe',cubic=True)
uc.set_repeat(2)
shift = [.1,.2,.3]
uc.positions
```

For example, I want to translate only atoms whose Z coordinate is less than 1:

```py
uc[uc.positions[:,2] < 1].positions += shift
uc.positions
```

Neither it moves atoms nor it returns any error.

However, translating only one atom or all atoms are working properly.

```py
uc.positions += shift
uc.positions
```

```py
uc[0].position += shift
uc[0]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This one should work:

```
uc.positions[uc.positions[:,2] < 1] += shift
```

In principle when you are working with `positions`, `cell` etc., it's always safer to use the setter/getter of the attributes (and not the setter/getter of `Atoms`). I personally use the setter of `Atoms` only to change atom species, e.g. `uc[0] = 'Ni'`.